# How to add an image inside clip SVG instead of a solid color

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a curve path SVG with text around it, using **`fill`** helps in adding a solid color, but I was wondering how to *add an image* instead of *solid color*

```
path {
  fill: red;
}
```

Here is the curve SVG snippet

```html
<div class="welcome">
  <svg viewBox="0 30 800 300">
      <path id="curve" d="M 200 300 A 50 50 0 1 1 600 300 L 600 550 L 200 550 L 200 300 " />
      <text class="home-text">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
          Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Here the Dummy Text is chained to the black circle path. See `id="curve"`

Comment: Yes I need that path to be an image instead of solid color